# Using python range function for multiplication

Tags: python-3.x

I'm glad to be here! I have a question referring to my python prp
programming course that I have been struggling to grasp! This assignment  has a question and basically I must define the function Power(x,n), which must raise the value x to the power of n! I am not aloud to use the operator "**" and also we can only use what was learned in the class so basically using if-else statements, boolean algebra, range, and for loops! It must only return a value for the inputted values! Help is greatly appreciated as I am struggling with this concept!
The range function must be used...Thanks! :)

Comment: Getting others to do your homework completely defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def power(x, n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(n):
        result *= x
    return result
```

Which gives you the correct answers. Examples:

```
>>> power(2, 3)
8
>>> 2**3
8
>>> 
>>> power(4, 6)
4096
>>> 4**6
4096
```

Or if you're allowed to use the math module you can include negatives and fractions by generalizing to:

```
def power(x, n):
    return math.exp(math.log(x) * n)
```

Returning:

```
>>> power(2, 0.5)
1.414213562373095
>>> power(2, -1)
0.5
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly,Its done so simply in your code! What I have been struggling with is the actual logic behind the maths! I have another two questions that Ill attempt now after I saw how you did that! Thanks :)

Comment: Might be out of scope, but what about negatives or not whole numbers?

Comment: Generalize it to: `math.exp(math.log(x) * n)`.

Answer (score -1):

By recursion instead it is prettier.

```
def power(n, k):
    return 1 if k == 0 else n*power(n, k-1)
```

or

```
def power(n, k):
    if k < 0:
        return 1 / power(n, abs(k))
    return 1 if k == 0 else n*power(n, k-1)
```

But if you must use a range object, you could build it up from addition instead.

```
def multiply(n, k):
    return sum(n for _ in range(k))

def power(n, k):
    return sum(multiply(n, n) for _ in range(k-1)) if k != 0 else 1
```

else you could do it like

```
def power1(n, k):
    return sum(n*n for _ in range(k-1)) if k != 0 else 1
```